# asp .net How to hide a TemplateField of a gridview column but still access its value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview which is loaded through a strored procedure. It has an ID column which i want to hide it but still access its value. I set the dataKeyNames and i have a method

```
     protected void grdTime_OnDataBound(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        grdTime.Columns[1].Visible = false;
    }
```

which i am trying to hide this column but i get the following error. If i remove the line inside the method it works. Here is the error.
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in the method and then check..

grdTime.Columns[0].Visible = false;

Answer (score 0):

hide the column in Row_Created event

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[1].CssClass = "hiddencol";
        //e.Row.Cells[2].CssClass = "hiddencol";
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[1].CssClass = "hiddencol";
        //e.Row.Cells[2].CssClass = "hiddencol";
    }
}
```

here `hiddencol` is a css class

```
.hiddencol
{
    display:none;
}
```

in the above code i'm hiding second column of my grid

Answer (score 0):

If you've set GridView's [`AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) to `true`(default), the Columns-Collection is empty. Following should work then:

1.)

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
        e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
}
```

2.)

```
foreach (TableRow row in GridView1.Controls[0].Controls)
{
    row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this in gridview tag on .aspx page

```
<Columns>

      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Merchandise Id" DataField="MerchandiseId"  Visible="false" /></columns>
```